# Can I put variables inside literal css in stylus?

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

I have a function in stylus that looks like this

```
// Shortcut for top-down gradient background color
td_gradient(color1, color2)
    background-color (color1 + (color2 - color1) / 2)
    background -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(color1), to(color2))
    background -webkit-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    background -moz-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    background -ms-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    background -o-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    @css
    {
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=color1, endColorstr=color2);
    }
```

I have to wrap the Internet Explorer gradient style inside the literal css scope `@css`, otherwise it crashes stylus. Probably too many colons or something. In any case, the variables `color1` and `color2` are taken literally inside the css scope, which breaks the style.

Any way I can get the css scope to parse variables? Or is there a way I can get the filter style inside stylus without using the literal css scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
filter s('progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorstr=%s, EndColorstr=%s)', color1, color2))
```

But I urge you to check out [nib](https://github.com/visionmedia/nib), also by TJ. In particular, he's built a mixin that auto-generates a gradient image in png, and base64-encodes it into the stylesheet. The only caveat is that you need to specify height (or width, for horizontal gradients), but that should be fine for your td:s.

**UPDATE:** A little cleaner:

```
filter 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorstr=%s, EndColorstr=%s)' % (color1 color2)
```